# Multiple frames lost if I use av_read_frame in FFmpeg

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I have an HEVC sequence with 3500 frames and I am writing a decoder for reading it (read frame by frame and dump to yuv). In my main(), I have a for loop that calls a decoder() 3500 times (I am assuming at this stage that the main() knows how many frames there are).

So, for every call to decoder(), I need a complete frame to be returned. This is what the decoder() looks like..

```
bool decode(pFormatCtx, pCodecCtx)
{
    int gotaFrame=0;

    while (gotaFrame==0) {

        printf("1\t");

        if ( !av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet) ) { 
            if(packet.stream_index==videoStreamIndex) {

                // try decoding
                avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &gotaFrame, &packet);

                if (gotaFrame) {  // decode success.

                    printf("2\t");

                    // dump to yuv ... not shown here. 

                    // cleanup
                    av_frame_unref(pFrame);
                    av_frame_free(&pFrame);
                    av_free_packet(&packet);

                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The behavior is like this: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 ...... it looks like it reads several frames before decoding one? The first frame is an I-frame, so shouldn't that be decoded right away?

With this code, I end up losing the several frames (indicated by the series of 1s). Can someone help me out here? Is there something I am doing wrong in my code?

Update: the test clip is video-only. No audio.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are seeing is the correct behavior. The decoder bufferers a few frames for multithreaded efficiency. And it may take several frames to 'prime the pump' as it were. Basically, to keep your program responsive, avcodec_decode_video2 queues up the frame for decoding, then returns. This prevents your program from blocking for a long time. It is also absolutely required to delay decoding in the case of B frames where the decode order may not be the same as the display order.

So, how to not lose these frames? After av_read_frame stops returning new frames, you must flush the decoder by calling avcodec_decode_video2 with empty packets until no more frames are retuned.

Comment: Thanks @szatmary -- this worked for me. I kept track of how many packets were read without dumping out a frame and then at the end, I read out that many frames using NULL/0 packets.

Comment: @szatmary, thanks so much for the clear explanation. This worked for me. I had to send a freshly-inited packet instead of null. In other words, I had to call av_initi_packet and pass the AVPacket* to avcodec_decode_video2 in order to effectively pull from the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

What most propably fail is the test `if(packet.stream_index==videoStreamIndex)`, not `av_read_frame`: your may be reading packets from another stream (for example, audio stream packets are flagged as "i-frames").

For your first I-Frame, it is quite common that an I-frame needs two packets to be decoded (i.e. the first call to `avcodec_decode_video2` returns  `gotaFrame == 0`)

Comment: I commented out the 'if(packet.stream_index==videoStreamIndex)' but I still get the same behavior. Also, the clip contains only video (no audio) -- I updated my question to reflect that.  So, if the I-frame needs two packets -- does that mean I lose one frame? I read that a packet need not contain a full frame, but the way my experiment is coming along, I am losing frames.

Comment: If you comment out the stream_index test, you will have the same behaviour, because decode_video will always fail if it does not have the correct codecContext. Instead, try to move your "1" log (or add another) between the read_frame and the stream_index test. It could be metadata, another video, or any stream, not an audio stream. You can be sure of the stream part by checking that `pFormatCtx->nb_streams == 1`. If still not that, check the avcodec_decode_video2 return value: if there is an error, it will tell you more than simply `gotaFrame == 0`

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I did what you suggested and it seems that `if(gotaFrame)` loop is the one that is skipped for the first several times. I checked the return value of avcodec_decode_video2 and this is what I got `retval=33149 
retval=6715 
retval=767 
retval=264 
retval=126 
retval=147 
retval=286 
retval=140 
retval=141 
retval=7243 
retval=568 
retval=315 
retval=95 
retval=146 
retval=328 
retval=159 
retval=121 
retval=7010 
retval=571 
retval=309 2` sorry for the formatting! Looks like 33149 bytes were returned for the 1st frame which looks like an I frame. But still  getaFrame=0!

Comment: Does your input stream use bidirectional frames (b-frames)?