# FFMpeg avcodec_decode_video2 no result for first frame

Tags: android, ffmpeg, h.264

I'm trying to play video from my archive. Playing is OK except very first frame: got_picture_ptr is setting to 0. And starting from 2nd frame everything is ok. Because of this I can't retreive an image when seeking with timeline. Frame size is same in send from archive function and in decode function. Why decoding may fail?

```
AVPacket packet;
    av_init_packet(&packet);
    packet.data = (uint8_t*) frame->data;
    packet.size = frame->size;
    int decode_count = 0;
    bool pushed = false;
//  while(av_read_frame(formatContext, &packet) >= 0) {
        //decode_ret = avcodec_decode_video2(codec_context, pFrame, &got_picture, &packet);
    //}
    LOGDEBUG("Frame len: %d", packet.size);
    while (packet.size > 0) {
        decode_count++;
        int got_picture;
        int decode_ret = 0;
//      LOGDEBUG("Decoding [%d] (%d/%d, %d/%d) %d", getDecoderId(), codec_context->width, width, codec_context->height, height, packet.size);

        try {
            decode_ret = avcodec_decode_video2(codec_context, pFrame, &got_picture, &packet);
            LOGDEBUG("Decoding frame size decode_ret: %d, got_picture: %d, width: %d, height: %d", decode_ret, got_picture, codec_context->width, codec_context->height);
            decoded_frame_number = frame->index;
            if (decode_ret < 0) {
                LOGDEBUG("Decoding error %d", decode_ret);
                return false;
            }
        } catch (...) {
            LOGDEBUG("Error decoding");
            return false;
        }
        if (packet.data) {
            packet.size -= decode_ret;
            packet.data += decode_ret;
        }
        if (!got_picture) {
            LOGDEBUG("Waiting for full picture");
            std::string packet_flags = "";
            if (packet.flags & AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY) {
                packet_flags += "AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY";
            }
            if (packet.flags & AV_PKT_FLAG_CORRUPT) {
                packet_flags += " | AV_PKT_FLAG_CORRUPT";
            }
//          LOGDEBUG("Decoding %d frame[%ld] not complete (%d, %d) flags %s packetsize %d/%d keyframe %d for %d",
//                  decode_ret, frame->index, codec_context->width,
//                  codec_context->height, packet_flags.c_str(), packet.size, frame->size,
//                  pFrame->key_frame, decode_count);
            continue;
        }
```

Here is my full function: http://pastebin.com/TekkZEUa

P.S. codec context width and height is 0 after decoding first frame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy-Pase from
[Multiple frames lost if I use av_read_frame in FFmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25526075/multiple-frames-lost-if-i-use-av-read-frame-in-ffmpeg/25533696#25533696)

What you are seeing is the correct behavior. The decoder bufferers a few frames for multithreaded efficiency. And it may take several frames to 'prime the pump' as it were. Basically, to keep your program responsive, avcodec_decode_video2 queues up the frame for decoding, then returns. This prevents your program from blocking for a long time. It is also absolutely required to delay decoding in the case of B frames where the decode order may not be the same as the display order.

So, how to not lose these frames? After av_read_frame stops returning new frames, you must flush the decoder by calling avcodec_decode_video2 with empty packets until no more frames are retuned.

Comment: Still don't understand how to save very first frame. Decoder wasn't working yet, flushing wasn't called. Pumping with empty packets didn't working.

Comment: The first frame returned is the first frame passed in. It just will not happen in the same call.

Comment: Is there any way to turn off that behavior? I just want 1 frame without calling any further.